# Can I have the final leg of a multi-city flight refunded?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, refunds

I have a refundable ticket taking me from 'A' -> 'B' and then 'C' -> 'A'. However, I have now made further plans, so that I do not need the C -> A ticket anymore. So, given the limited travel budget that I have, I'd like to have the return / final leg of journey refunded.

The cost of the total flight was less than the one-way tickets from A -> B would be now, so it does not make sense for me to cancel the entire itinerary. I'd like to travel on the first leg, and have the second leg refunded if possible.

p.s. I am not getting off at any layover. The flights from A->B and C->A are more than 15 days apart and I have my own ways of traveling from B->C independent of the airline.

Comment: Yes, B->C is overland

Comment: the airline indicated a 25% cancellation fee (which I assume includes the admin fee) but insisted that I cannot only cancel the c->a flight. Is this a standard regulation, or are they supposed to cancel the C->A refundable ticket even if I am using the A->B ticket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your ticket conditions and the airline in question, but odds are pretty likely the answer is **no**.

What you have sounds like an **open-jaw return**: you've basically paid for A-B/B-A return as a single ticket, with a small surcharge to return from C instead.  Airlines will generally not refund any portion of a return ticket after the journey has begun (= you have flown one half of it), and this applies to open-jaw returns as well.

A "true" multi-city itinerary consists of a series of one-way flight tickets tacked onto each other.  These would usually let you refund individual segments, because they're separate tickets under the hood, but they also usually cost a lot more.

Comment: Yes, but once they do, I'm saying it's highly unlikely they'll be able refund C->A.

Comment: I am going to be flying Malaysian Airlines, and I have not flown on any of the flights yet. Shouldn't there be some sort of message or indication in the ticket that explains whether the ticket is a true multi-city ticket vs. the open-jaw return ticket you mentioned above? I'd have thought that the airlines would at least have to mention that the tickets cannot be cancelled separately.

Comment: @Joe You have not purchased "tickets".  You have purchased a single ticket, which consists of two linked flights, and I'd venture a guess that the small print on your ticket *does* explain that no cancellations or refunds will be allowed after you start traveling.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you cannot get a refund of the fare, you may be able to claim a refund of the *taxes* on the unused part of the ticket, which can amount to a significant proportion of its price. See e.g. [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117176/what-are-the-eu-laws-on-unused-plane-ticket-and-airport-tax-refund). The details depend on the country and airline.